# Div not displaying correctly on show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fenster = $(location).attr('href');

    if (fenster == 'http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/index.php/') {
        $('#intro-page').show(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                $(this).fadeOut(250);
            });
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

I have a `div` that needs to be displayed in full-screen as an intro. The problem is that it doesn't display correctly; it just displays itself in the top left corner and grows until its full-screen. Why is it doing this?

Comment: What are the CSS styles you applied for your DIV?

Comment: #intro-page {
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #FFF;
 display: none;
 z-index:99999;

}

Answer (score 2):

`show()` takes the duration of the animation as a first parameter. You have given it a function, which is incorrect. Either you meant to chain your methods:

```
$('#intro-page').show().click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(250);
});
```

Or, you *did* mean to put a callback function in there, but you missed out the first parameter; the duration:

```
$('#intro-page').show(250, function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(250);
    });
});
```

**Documentation**

- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: No problem :) Glad to have helped.

Comment: The first one… "only show #intro-page on the specific url … full-sized, after click, fade out…

Comment: …Somehow i get sometimes the problem (specific browsers, low internet speed) that the browser first loads the div that lies under the div "#intro-page" … How can I change that? Do I need to "hide" the div that lies under it an "show" it on a click function? (I am a bloody starter in JS)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fenster = $(location).attr('href');

    if (fenster == 'http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/index.php/') {
        $('#intro-page').show(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                $(this).fadeOut(250);
            });
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

try the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fenster = $(location).attr('href');

    if (fenster == 'http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/index.php/') {
        $('#intro-page').show();
        $('#intro-page').click(function(){
           // seperate it from show function call so you can have more access to object
           // and do logic on it.
           $(this).fadeOut(250);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You! …Works to great! But …Somehow sometimes I get the problem (specific browsers, low internet speed) that the browser first loads the div (or the side content) that lies under the div "#intro-page" … How can I change that? Do I need to "hide" the div that lies under it an "show" it on a click function? (I am a bloody starter in JS)

Comment: Tried it with this one here:

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fenster = $(location).attr('href');

    if (fenster == 'http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/index.php/') {
        $('#intro-page').show();
        $('#dapper').hide();
        $('#line').hide();
        $('#intro-page').click(function(){
           // seperate it from show function call so you can have more access to object
           // and do logic on it.
           $(this).fadeOut(250);
            $('#line').show();
           $('#dapper').show();
        
        });
    }
});
</script>

Comment: Yes in the tag of the element or in your css add the "display:none;" property and value. this will hide it until you decide to use $('selector').show(250); on it